# How to perform operations inside Cassandra Trigger?

Tags: cassandra

My application collects per sec data from devices and inserts into cassandra table. My idea is to write a trigger for the per sec data table which will automatically convert the per sec into hourly / daily data. And also I'll store the hourly and daily data in the same table with different key. To achieve this use case, I need to perform below operations inside my trigger code.

1. How can I insert a data into the same table which will invoke the trigger again  ?  ( will be used for converting per hour to per day )
2. How can I insert a data into different table ? ( store accumulated data into a temp table )
3. How can I select a data from different table ? ( fetch the last data for accumulation )

If I know the above info, my application will just insert per sec data and rest(per sec -to- hour -to- day convertion) will be automatically taken care by my trigger code.

Can you please help me to get the above info ?

It would be great if you give some code snippet for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're comfortable with Cassandra internals, you should do this in a data abstraction layer instead of a trigger.

Comment: You are right Jbellis. Thanks. Already I planned for the same. Before decide I wanted to know whether there is an easy way to do this or not.